# unable to cancel backgroundWorker out of infinite loop in C#/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, backgroundworker

## Edit2:

After adding the answer below I also had to get rid of my placeholder `while(true);` infinite loop. This is working so far and should probably work as well.

```
private void lookForXml(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"\\filepath";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite| 
            NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        while (!bw.CancellationPending) {
            if (bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

## Edit:

After changing my XAML to:

`<Button Content="End" Style="{StaticResource LargeButton}"  Command="{Binding EndCommand}"/>`

I get an NullReferenceError in EndXmlImport that says my bgWorker is not set to an instance of an object. So I guess how do I associate my cancel button with the process that is currently running so that I can cancel it?

---

I currently am trying to write a program that will look for XML files in a directory until the user tells the program to stop. However, I can't seem to associate my cancel button press with the cancellation of the BackgroundWorker. I am not sure how I can link the cancel button in XAML to cancel the backgroundWorker process.

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Import" Style="{StaticResource LargeButton}" Margin="0 20 0 0" Command="{Binding ImportCommand}"/>
<Button Content="End" Style="{StaticResource LargeButton}"  Command="{Binding EndXmlImport}"/>
```

C#:

```
public SubmissionImporterViewModel()
{
    ImportCommand = new RelayCommand(ImportSubmission) ;
    EndCommand = new RelayCommand(EndXmlImport);
}

public void EndXmlImport(object sender)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    bgWorker.CancelAsync();

}

public void ImportSubmission(object o)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(lookForXml);
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(afterCancel);
    bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    Status = "Looking for .xml files";
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: `sender` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: I guess I don't necessarily think that sender is a BackgroundWorker but I am not sure how to make it so that it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code you include in a WPF code behind? If so, make the BackgroundWorker a member reference so it is accessible in the EndXmlImport method.

```
public void EndXmlImport(object sender)
{
    bgWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;

public void ImportSubmission(object o)
{
    bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(lookForXml);
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(afterCancel);
    bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    Status = "Looking for .xml files";
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had some other problems when I was dealing with my infinite loop as well but I certainly needed this to get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you bind your end button to EndCommand?  Like this

```
<Button Content="End" Style="{StaticResource LargeButton}"  Command="{Binding EndCommand}"/>
```

If you use MVVM design pattern and you bind your VM to View then you can move bgWorker to the class level and then reference it EndXmlImport function, since you can't get sender on VM.

If you use code behind, then sender is not your BackgroundWorker, but most likely it's button instance.

Comment: Okay so if I stay with the code behind approach is there a way to get the backgroundworker instance and cancel it? Sorry this is my first time using XAML/C#/backgroundworker in conjunction

Comment: Then just use a private field to reference the Backgroundworker in your code behind... _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker() etc. When the command gets fired (if you manage to do so ;) then check if _backgroundworker != null and cancel it. Might be so that in the execution method of the worker you continuously have to check if cancelation flag is set and then take appropriate action...